# Is my Python code doing what I expect for the following summation?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

Here is my python code, I am performing a summation that will be linked here and I am using python to perform this summation. Are they equivalent?[image: MSE formula]

Note, x_hat (filled array) is x_hat[n] in the equation and x (filled array) is x[n]. The loop below is only for filling the arrayMSE[] array with numerous values to plot against SNR. I am trying to perform a summation within this loop using sum() without using another for loop.

```
for i,SNR_loop in enumerate(SNR):
      # all other stuff here is irrelevant. Is the code below equivalent 
      # to the picture?
      MSE = (1/N)*sum((x_hat-x)**2)       # summation temp variable
      arrayMSE.append(MSE)                # appending to list for plotting
      MSE_inv_array.append(1/MSE)         # 1/temp for plotting w.r.t SNR
```

If these are not equivalent why? What changes need to be made to make this equivalent (preferably without another for loop for speed)?

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: I have, however it does not look like they're equivalent. Is there a way to keep some kind of sum() syntax to keep them equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
xh = [xh_1, 
      xh_2, 
      ...
      xh_n]

x = [x_1, 
     x_2, 
     ...
     x_n]

(xh - x) = [(xh_1 - x_1),
            (xh_2 - x_2),
                 ...
            (xh_n - x_n)]

(xh - x)**2 = [(xh_1 - x_1)**2,
               (xh_2 - x_2)**2,
                    ...
               (xh_n - x_n)**2]

sum((xh - x)**2) = (xh_1 - x_1)**2 + (xh_2 - x_2)**2 + ... + (xh_n - x_n)**2
```

Hopefully you can see that this is equivalent to your equation. Let me know if I need to explain any of the steps.

---

This would look much nicer if I could use the embeded Latex like on Math.SE

Comment: That is how I assumed the sum() function would operate, although my answer is not the same as when I plug it into my calculator. Now that I know this function isn't doing anything weird with my array's, I can search in the construction of x_hat to find my bug.

Comment: Look in the documentation for [sum()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum). And you could be using [numpy's sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) in your case.